# Installing and running MySQL and PostgreSQL-8.4 side by side

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Are there any configuration or installation hazards to setup both Postgresql-8.4 and MySQL on the same server and running them side by side, other than performance?

The server is running Debian etch.

Thanks

Comment: I've had MySQL and PostgreSQL running side by side on a test server for several years without a problem. As you say, though, performance may be an issue on a production server, depending on the workload.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i do have similar configuration live. they [ mysql-server-5.0 and postgresql-8.3 [ not 8.4 as you ask ]] work fine together.

it's not like with smtp servers postfix vs exim - mysql and postgres do not replace each other from the system perspective. but obviously those two db engines will compete for system resources [ cpu, io ] if you are going to put high load on them [ but there is nothing wrong with it ].

Comment: Agreed. The only issue I expect that you would see is the two competing for CPU/memory resources. If you have enough CPU power and RAM to go around then all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will work correctly.

Comment: Do you have a similar configuration currently live?

Comment: Yes. You may also be interrested by http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

No should run OK - and you can even minimise performance issues if you have their data on separate physical drives and enough RAM/cores.